# How to uninstall driver forcefully

Tags: drivers, uninstall, broadcom

I have a Broadcom 440x 10/100 Integrated Controller Ethernet card whose driver I need to uninstall, whenever I go to Add/Remove programs to uninstall the driver, I get "Fatal Error during Installation."

I redownloaded the driver, and tried to reinstall like that, but it always tries to remove the old driver first (and fails with unexpected interruption during installation).

So, I know the driver is corrupted and I just want to completely get rid of it. Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I would try is uninstalling the device driver from device manager.

Start -> Run -> devmgmt.msc
Right click on the device and choose "Uninstall"

You may also want to right click on the device and do "Update Driver". Point it to the location of the new driver. You will need to make sure the driver has been extracted from the setup file first.

If you absolutely have to rip it out, try this:
http://techgurulive.com/2008/09/08/how-to-remove-original-equipment-manufacturer-drivers-in-windows-2000-in-windows-xp-and-in-windows-2003/

This removes the driver from the driver cache.

EDIT: Are there any events generated during the uninstall? Start -> Run -> eventvwr.msc and see if anything has appeared.